# how can I say "I have a long hair" which I'd like to have it cut?

Tags: grammar

rather than say I'd like to have my long hair how can I form this version:

I have a long hair which I'd like to have it cut (OR only "have cut"? or how?)

thank you

Comment: I am confused by your use of "a" with "hair" in this context: "a hair" means a single strand of hair, like a piece you could pluck. Normally, when people get hair cut, they are talking about the mass of hair overall, composed of many hairs, so you would not use the indefinite singular article "a" because it's not used with mass nouns

Comment: The construction *[there is an  X,] which I'd like to have **it** [treated]* is dialectal/obsolete. These days we don't include a pronoun *(**it**)* to refer back to the original noun *(**an X**)* in such contexts (effectively, the "back-reference" is already covered by ***which***).

Comment: @sumelic: Normally, when talking about what a hairdresser does for them, people include a determiner - either *get **a** haircut* (single-word noun) or *get **their** hair cut* (noun plus past participle verb).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your answer, but then it becomes, "I have long hair which I'd like to have cut" may it then not confuse the listener that it's me who cut my own hair while I want to say someone else does it..? how to make t both grammatically concise and correct and at the same time give clear meaning that the hair is cut by someone else?

Comment: Saying *I have long hair which I'd like to **have** cut* strongly implies *...cut **by someone else***. If you wanted to cut it *yourself*, you'd ditch ***have*** and just say *...which I'd like to cut*.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your hair is long and you want it all to be short, you could say:

> I have long hair, and I'd like to have it cut.
>   I have long hair, which I'd like to have cut.

If you have a single strand of hair that is long and needs to be shortened, you'd say:

> I have a long hair, which I'd like to have cut.

The article "a" is what tells us you're talking about a single strand of hair. Otherwise, "my hair" refers to the collection of all of your strands of hair.

If you have a lot of long hair and only want some of it to be cut, you have to use an extra word to describe which section you want to be shorter.

> I have long hair, and I'd like this section to be cut.
>   I have long hair, and I'd like to cut off this chunk.
>   I have long hair, and I'd like to have this area trimmed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but then it becomes, "I have long hair which I'd like to have cut" may it then not confuse the listener that it's me who cut my own hair while I want to say someone else does it..? how to make t both grammatically concise and correct and at the same time give clear meaning that the hair is cut by someone else?